# Conflito em eventos com jquery

Tags: jquery, funções, menu, eventos

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
$('#abre-busca').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'opacity':0});
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'display':'inline-block'});
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'opacity':1});
        },100);
    },500);
});
$(document).click(function(event){

    if($(event.target) != $('#barra-busca')){
        $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'opacity':0});
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'display':'none'});
            $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'display':'inline-block'});
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'opacity':1});
            },100);
        },500); 
    }else{
    }
});
```

Quero que, ao clicar fora de `#barra-busca`, a mesma feche e dê espaço aos outros elementos que serão mostrados, porém, ocorre que ao clicar fora dela, nada acontece, e ao clicar nela, ou nos elementos de dentro dela, a mesma executa a ação de se esconder e mostrar os outros elementos.

Como posso corrigir ?

FIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/g0am9rvs/

LINK do site

http://narglothstore.16mb.com/peregrino-web/

Comment: Pode criar um Fiddle pra ficar mais facil de reproduzir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar esse tipo de mudanca siga o seguinte codigo:
As aleracoes que realizei foi ao inves de usar css, usei a funcao show ou hide do jquery e no click fora eu valido pelo typeof.

Segue o codigo abaixo:

```js
$('#abre-busca').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'opacity':0});
 setTimeout(function(){
  $('#menu-principal-sub li').hide();
  $('#menu-principal-sub form').show();
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'opacity':1});
  },100);
 },500);
});
$(document).click(function(event){

 if(typeof $(event.target).attr("id") == "undefined"){
  $('#menu-principal-sub form').css({'opacity':0});
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#menu-principal-sub form').hide();
   $('#menu-principal-sub li').show();
   setTimeout(function(){
    $('#menu-principal-sub li').css({'opacity':1});
   },100);
  },500); 
 }else{
 }
});
```

```css
.container-inf{position:relative;background-color:inherit;}
.container-inf .container{padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;position:relative;}
.container-inf #menu-principal-sub li{display:inline-block;opacity:1;transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out;}
.container-inf .navbar-nav li a:hover{color:#7b7b7b!important;}
.navbar-nav li .active{color:#0689bd!important;}
.search-form{position:absolute;right:2.5%;top:50%;width:30%;transform:translateY(-50%);opacity:0;transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out;display:none;box-sizing:border-box;padding:7px;}
.search-form fieldset{position:relative;width:100%;}
.search-form input{width:90%;padding:8px;box-sizing:border-box;border:none;}
.search-form button{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;width:8%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);border:none;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:1.2em;}
```

```html
<div id="total">


<ul id="menu-principal-sub">
 <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Como participar</a></li>
  <li><a href="" id="abre-busca">Busca</a></li>
 <form class="search-form" action="" method="" id="barra-busca">
  <fieldset>
   <input type="text" id="txtBusca" name="txtBusca" placeholder="Digite aqui a sua busca">
   <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: continua sumindo ao clicar em cima dele, e as vezes a barra nem chega a aparecer

Comment: Voce diz com relacao ao clique no input da busca ?

Comment: isso mesmo :) e quando clico pra abrir o input, ele também não abre

Comment: Da uma olhada alterei o codigo

Comment: ainda, ao clicar na barra ela some :/ resolvi colocar um icone pra fechar, mas sua resposta foi a mais completa, ela resolveu pelo menos o problema de clicar para mostrar e não mostrar

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#abre-busca').click(function(event) {
  $('#menu-principal-sub form').addClass('active');
  return false;
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var elClick = $(e.target);
  var elParent = elClick.closest('ul');

  if (!elParent.hasClass('menu-principal-sub')) {
    $('#menu-principal-sub form').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.container-inf {
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.container-inf .container {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.container-inf #menu-principal-sub li {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
.container-inf .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #7b7b7b!important;
}
.navbar-nav li .active {
  color: #0689bd!important;
}
.search-form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.5%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 7px;
}
.search-form.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
.search-form fieldset {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.search-form input {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
}
.search-form button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 8%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-principal-sub" class="menu-principal-sub">
  <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Como participar</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" id="abre-busca">Busca</a>
  </li>
  <form class="search-form" action="" method="" id="barra-busca">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Digite aqui a sua busca">
      <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>dasdasdsadas
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ele continua escondendo a barra de busca ao clicar nela mesma

Comment: Certeza, mano ? Aqui não.

Comment: Coloquei o link dele rodando em um server, por enquanto não tem um responsivo dele, roda melhor em 1920px